# variance of autocorrelated series

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation

I have simulated a series with autocorrelation of 50%. When I compute the variance of the series it is 1/2 of the variance of the white noise series. Could somebody show me the math behind this result?

Comment: Can't be. For an $AR(1)$ process with $\rho =0.5$, the variance of the process should be $4/3$ of the white noise variance, not half. You should check carefully the code you used to generate the autocorrelated series. Related to (but not duplicate of) the - unanswered- post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50657/variance-of-a-series-of-correlated-variables?rq=1

Comment: All clear - you're right sorry. I was puzzled as I'm familiar with the $\frac{\sigma}{1-\phi^2}$ result but I was getting a very different answer ..but that because the series wasn't AR(1) :)